# Move textview animation android from position 1 to position 2

Tags: animation, textview

[image]

I want to ask about animation in android.

What's different between

```
TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
```

and

```
TranslateAnimation(int fromXType, float fromXValue, int toXType, float toXValue, int fromYType, float fromYValue, int toYType, float toYValue)
```

If I have 2 textview belong a layout, I want to move text1 to text2, I coded:

```
animation = new TranslateAnimation(txt1.getX(),txt2.getX(), 
txt1.getY(),txt2.getY());
```

But when run code, the text 1 move other position text2.
What should I do?

Thanks for your help :))